# How to verify a condition that can be changed frequently

Tags: c#, .net, list, web-config

I am having a list of alphanumeric (string) values that I am anticipating in response. The response will ideally have one from that list. I want to validate a condition to see if a value is present in the subset of the list. The subset contains list of alphanumeric values that can be added or deleted by business.

In this scenario, I am planning to put the values in web.config file

For example: I am having subset `responseValues = { "A1", "B2", "D45" }`

I want to check:

```
if ( value IN { responseValues } )
{
 // Do something
}
```

The responseValues is changeable by business, so I don't want to hard code those values in code, but want to come up with a better design of having that in DB or in web.config file.

I can do something like below in web.config file?

Please help me under what section should I add or just a key value pair with a single key?

```
<add key = "ResponseValues" value="A1, B2, D45"/>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `.Contains`

Comment: ok I can do, but i dont know syntax, I am relatively new to programming. pls help on how to get these in C#

Comment: string[]  values = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["ResponseValues"].Split(",");

Comment: Then values.Contains?

Comment: `if (responseValues.Contains(value))`

Comment: The [F1] key in VS will take you directly to a page with everything you need to know about `Contains` or any other correctly spelled keyword.  Especially helpful to those "relatively new to programming"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have some configurable values you have this possibilities: 
 1. External repository DB, XML, txt, JSON files ..:
  **PROS**: the user can change this values trough some administration front end.

 2. WebConfig:
 **PROS**: the user can change this values trough some administration front end
 **CONS**: each time you modify it, the application pool will restart and session state will be lost => if you are using Form authentication all users will be logged out. 

 3. Hard-coded:
 **CONS**: only the developer can change the values
 **CONS**: violates the Open Close Principle 
 **CONS**: depending on where do you put the hard-coded values the session state can pe lost when you change the values

Comment: Thoughtful. Whats the difference between having such dynamic configurable values in web.config and DB tables? I know both approach are far better than hard coding

Comment: In DB or some other kinds of repository(xml, txt) you can give the power to the user to change this values - make a front end, some settings window, where they can change this values. For the  webconfig i told you my opinion, and  with the hard-coded approach  only the developer can change this, and it also violates the Open Close Principle.